# Visible and safe laser beam for lit areas

Tags: laser

In an application, I need a laser beam that is safe for indirect exposure and has visible beam in lit areas. I understand that 5mW is the maximum power commonly used without the need of safety glasses but 5mW lasers don't seem to have strong visible beams. Is there any work around /suggestions?

My application only requires laser beams to be visible from 5cm-200cm.

Comment: A laser beam is only visible if there is something in the air (dust or smoke, for example) to scatter the light into viewer's eyes.

Comment: Use dry ice machines?

Comment: Very creative! although I can't use it in this application

Comment: As ThePhoton wrote, you can't see light unless it is scattered. What you're asking for is not going to happen otherwise. When you look up at the moon at night, can you see the enormous amount of sunlight travelling through space before it hits the moon? No. So what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @ArashRowshan, we need to know what you're actually trying to do here.

Comment: My application is not taking place in vacuum. Most of the articles that I read focus on power when it comes to the difference in visibility in dusty or clean air. For example this good old wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_pointer
Also this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=woiTedSKPrk
Thanks guys. It seems I need to focus more on creating the dust or water droplets.

Answer (score 2):

Higher powered lasers can be used if the average energy hitting the eye is kept below the danger level. This is commonly achieved by pulsing the laser. This is also the strategy for laser shows. Pulsing time depends on laser CW output, wavelength and beam diameter.
I would suggest to ask a laser safety expert for help.